show that set function is finitely additive

Let be $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ two semi-rings and $\mu_1:\mathcal{H}_1\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and $\mu_2:\mathcal{H}_2\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ two content functions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_(measure_theory)). Show that $\mu:\mathcal{H}_1\boxtimes\mathcal{H}_2\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ by $\mu:=\mu_1\cdot \mu_2$ is finitely additive.

My approach:
Let be $S=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nS_i$ a disjoint union with $S,S_i\in\mathcal{H}_1\boxtimes\mathcal{H}_2$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. So there exist sets such that $S=A\times B$ and $S_i=A_i\times B_i$ where $A,A_i\in \mathcal{H}_1$ and $B,B_i\in \mathcal{H}_2$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. We immediately see that $A=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i$ and $B=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nB_i$.
Now, we choose a $x\in A_i\cap A_j$ where $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$. However, this means $x\in A_i\times B_i$ and $x\in A_j\times B_j$ which is a contradiction because both sets are assumed to be disjoint. Hence, $ A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for all $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$. Following the same reasoning also shows that $ B_i\cap B_j=\emptyset$ for all $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$.
If $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i$ isn't dijoint (with respect to the index $i$) then we already know that we can construct a disjoint union by $C_i:=A_i\setminus\{A_1,\dotsc,A_{i-1}\}$. Of course, same holds for $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nB_i$, so henceforth we assume that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i$ and $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nB_i$ are both disjoint unions, respectively. Keeping that in mind, we apply the definition of a content and its properties and get
\begin{align*}
&\mu(A\times B)=\mu_1(A)\cdot \mu_2(B)=\mu_1\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i\right)\cdot \mu_2\left(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^nB_j\right)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\mu_1(A_i)\mu_2(B_j)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mu_1(A_i)\mu_2(B_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i\times B_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mu(S_i)
\end{align*}
because $\mu_1(A_i)\mu_2(B_j)=\mu(A_i\times B_j)=\mu(\emptyset)=0$ for all $1\leq i\neq j\leq n$. Finally, $\mu$ is finitely additive.

I am a bit unsure if this is correct because the proof in our lecture is over 2 pages long and uses newly constructed unions of $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i$ and $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nB_i$ that are not only disjoint but also subordinate. Is it wrong to irgnore this fact?
